# How to create a RouteValueDictionary given a virtual path

Tags: asp.net, routes, system.web.routing

I would like to know if there is a method that, given a virtual path, will return a collection of parameter names and values for a route that matches the path. I need this to get the parameters of the URL on the target page without resorting to hard-coding a regular expression.

This is I guess the reverse of RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath that takes a RouteValueDictionary and returns a virtual path.

Is this possible?

Mark

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at my similar question and answers to it: [String URL to RouteValueDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481565/string-url-to-routevaluedictionary)

**Edit**

[Piotr Czapla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80869/piotr-czapla) had provided solution that does not require mocking library. Take a look if you are still interested in solving this problem