# How to parse a url string using mvc2 routes

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I'd like to know if there is a simple way of building a RouteValueDictionary from a url. For example if I have a url http://www.site.com/controllerA/actionB/idC, then how can I extract the RouteValueDictionary where the item with the key controller would have the value of controllerA.

Note this isn't for testing so I don't want to use mocking and the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481565/string-url-to-routevaluedictionary) does not seem to be working.

Comment: Where would you like/need this code to be run from? What exactly would you use it for?

Comment: It's used for a help system where the url is parsed and rules are used to identity the help id for the given url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was never an issue addressed by MVC so I have written by own URL parser. Although reflector does help a bit.