# Convert URL string to area + action + controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I get a URL string (not the current route) in my action, I want to know how my routes definitions will parse the URL into `Area`, `Controller` and  `Action`

example:

```
"http://website.com/Selling/Products/UpdateProduct/2"

area == "Selling"
controller == "Products"
action == "UpdateProduct"
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1831825/601179) answer from **2-12-2009** with a way how to do it, but it's verbose:
it creates `HttpRequst`, `HttpResponse`, `HttpContext` and `HttpContextWrapper`! for a simple operation, that doesn't really need HTTP context environment.

Is there a better way today with `Asp.Net-Mvc3` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way today with Asp.Net-Mvc3 ?

No, the answer you saw is actually the way to go.

Comment: -1 I think it's not self explaining answer, what do you mean?

Comment: @IamStalker, I mean that the answer that the OP has linked to in his question is the way to go if you want to parse a string into its constituent elements. I also mean that even if this answer dates from 2-12-2009 it is still valid today and that there are no new classes in ASP.NET MVC 3 that allow you to do this. Sorry if my answer wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Phil Haack's [RouteDebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx).