# ASP.NET Razor get Area in URL

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-areas

Is there a way using the ASP.NET Razor Syntax to get the area component from a request?

```
http://localhost:12345/SomeController/SomeAction
http://localhost:12345/MyArea/AnotherController/AnotherAction
```

I'd like to use Razor to cleanly and reliably get me the "MyArea" part of the URL.

What's the best approach for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually used this:

```
var area = ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  Most of what I have read has said create a html helper class.  Soooooo much code for a simple thing.  Thanks for keeping it simple!  Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on another post:

[String URL to RouteValueDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481565/string-url-to-routevaluedictionary)

```
var request = new HttpRequest(null, "http://localhost:3333/Home/About", "testvalue=1");
var response = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
var httpContext = new HttpContext(request, response);
var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
```

And then to get the area:

```
string area = routeData.DataTokens["area"].ToString();
```

Alternatively, you might be able to just use:

```
var action = RouteData.Values["area"];
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```
@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("area").RawValue.ToString()
```

Comment: This returns a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @AdamLevitt You may need to check that the return value of GetValue("area") is not null.  I assume a null value means you do not have an area.